# PHP Session Variables not Giving a Value

Tags: php, session-variables

**Found the solution. Solution at the bottom of the post**

I have some code in php using sessions (I'm just testing them out - I want to use them in a login system).

test1.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION["test"] = "works";
echo $_SESSION["test"];

?>
```

test2.php:

```
<?php

echo $_SESSION["test"];

?>
```

test1.php output the correct value (where I wrote `echo $_SESSION["test"];`), however when I switch to test2.php, there's nothing. I have checked the cookies (both websites have the same session cookie). Could the problem be a server error?

**Found the solution. A simple error like that can create a big problem. At the time, I did not realize that I had to have a `session_start()` at the beginning of every php webpage that I used session variables in.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a `sesssion_start();` at the beginning of **EVERY** php webpage that you are using session variables in